# Knex.js: Create table and insert data

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Given that I have a Knex.js script like this:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('persons', function(table) {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name').notNullable();
    });
};
```

which currently creates a table.

How do I add subsequent insert statements to this script?

What I want to do is add a line like this (or similar):

```
knex.insert({id: 1, name: 'Test'}).into('persons')
```

I'm not sure I understand how this promise-based approach works. Am I supposed to write another script with insert statements? Or can I somehow append them to my existing script?

Unfortunately, I don't find any *complete* example of create + insert in Knex.js documentation.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The **then** method returns a **Promise**, which you can use to implement insertion after you have created the table. For example:

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.createTableIfNotExists("payment_paypal_status", function (table) {
            table.increments(); // integer id

            // name
            table.string('name');

            //description
            table.string('description');
        }).then(function () {
                return knex("payment_paypal_status").insert([
                    {name: "A", description: "A"},
                    {name: "B", description: "BB"},
                    {name: "C", description: "CCC"},
                    {name: "D", description: "DDDD"}
                ]);
            }
        ),
    ]);
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
    return Promise.all([
        knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("payment_paypal_status")
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes much more sense than the answer I came up with. Lack of experience with Promises got in my way here.

Comment: Hello. New to knex and Bookshelf. Just curious to know why use up and down for method names, I mean how are they used later in the code

Comment: These methods used to upgrade or downgrade database scheme (structure) usually you don't use these functions from your code you use and create these files from the terminal command line, Knex library try to make it more safe for you to change your database structure specially when you want to reflect your database structure  changes from local or development database to your production database every time you upgrade your database the up function will run and the version of the current database will save inside a special database table called migrate and the opposite  when you downgrade

Comment: no need for the Promise.all wrapping this by the way.

Answer (score 5):

With modern Javascript's `await/async` keywords, you could do it like this:

```
exports.up = async function(knex) {
    await knex.schema.createTable('persons', function(table) {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name').notNullable();
    });

    // You could replace "return" by "await" here if you wish.
    return knex.insert({id: 1, name: 'Test'}).into('persons');
};
```

It's basically the same, except using `await/async` instead of `then`.

Answer (score 3):

The then method returns a Promise, which you can use to implement insertion after you have created the table. For example:

```
exports.up = (knex) => {
    return knex.schema
        .createTable("payment_paypal_status", (table) => {
            table.increments()
            table.string("name")
            table.string("description")
        })
        .then(() =>
            knex("payment_paypal_status").insert([
                {name: "A", description: "A"},
                {name: "B", description: "BB"},
                {name: "C", description: "CCC"},
                {name: "D", description: "DDDD"},
            ])
        )
}

exports.down = (knex) => {
    return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("payment_paypal_status")
}
```

[PS.:](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/1303)

> Since .createTableIfNotExists actually just generates plain "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST..." query it will not work correctly if there are any alter table queries generated for columns afterwards. To not break old migrations this function is left untouched for now, but it should not be used when writing new code and it is removed from documentation.

I used the [Fareed Alnamrouti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427622/fareed-alnamrouti) example/code and follow the suggestion to discard `Promise.All` by [Jonny Rathbone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8588970/jonny-rathbone)